programmatic way to get parent stylesheet for computed style on HTML element?
In Chrome, I can inspect an element, view its computed styles, and for each property, see not only the computed value, but a link to the stylesheet from which it came.
The question: how might I obtain that same stylesheet reference programmatically?
Note that I use Chrome here for illustrative purposes only.  A browser-independent answer would be excellent, but I'll gladly accept any (scriptable) solution I can run via Chrome, Firefox, Edge, or Safari.
I know I can get to all stylesheets and rules by iterating over document.styleSheets.  But that doesn't indicated which of them "won" (provided the final computed value) for any given element and property.
I've also looked at Window.getComputedStyle() and Element.computedStyleMap().  These indicate the winning rules and values, but (far as I can tell) don't make any reference to the parent stylesheet.
Many thanks in advance!
Nutt

I don't think there's an API for this. DevTools has access to the internal DOM data that's used to compute it.

Thanks @Barmar for the quick response!  I'm beginning to suspect that too.
